# How to run exe from bat file with UserInteractive=false

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, cmd, windows-services

I created console app, which, if run as exe, uses Console to interact with user (for debug purposes) and, if run from bat-file must install a topshelf service. But now i have a problem, because when execute such a bat file:

```
cd "%~dp0"
TCPAgent.exe install
```

UserInteractive is true (because bat file creates a console window) and my programm appears. How can i get topshelf service installed? I don't want to create a bat file to run file, because for me it looks like an overkill...

Here is code of y Programm.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            var agent = new TcpAgent();
            agent.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
            agent.Stop();

        }
        else
        {
            HostFactory.Run(
            x =>
            {
                x.Service<TCPAgentServiceControl>(
                    s =>
                    {
                        s.ConstructUsing(name => new TCPAgentServiceControl());
                        s.WhenStarted((control, hostControl) => control.Start(hostControl));
                        s.WhenStopped((control, hostControl) => control.Stop(hostControl));
                    });
                x.UseNLog(LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Factory);
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            });
        }
    }
```

I'll be gratefull for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should pass your value as a command-line argument in your bat file. When you run it in console the project will not get the comment-line argument, therefore it will be in debug-mode